# Rails 3 Giving and error after saving models into mysql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Got a random error using rails 3

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

And when I try

```
Picture.create :content_type => :test
```

I get

```
TypeError: can't convert nil into Integer
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:318:in `uniq'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:318:in `commit_transaction_records'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:165:in `transaction'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:251:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:239:in `save'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `create'
from (irb):4
```

And this is what my migration looks like

```
  class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def self.up
    create_table :pictures do |t|
       t.string :title
       t.string :content_type
       t.string :url
       t.float :lat
       t.float :long
       t.string :hash 
       t.timestamps
    end
   end

   def self.down
     drop_table :pictures
   end
 end
```

But the data actually does get saved? Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by using the reserved word 'hash' in your model.  Though i often have difficulty remembering this, a simple rule is to never name columns after any of Ruby's reserved words.

If you are using an MD5 hash, or something for your photos, you should rename the column 'hash' to 'md_hash'.

Answer (score -1):

Does the ID field get created with the database record? It seems like the ID field is your only integer and it may not be getting returned correctly on create.